# How to choose "start" values in function stats4::mle in R?

Tags: r, statistics, mle

It's bad I can't provide a reproducible code of my problem, because I use a big vector. But the question is still rather clear.
What I'm trying to do is to fit a beta distribution with **mle** function:

```
params <- mle(nll, start = list(alpha = 0.1, beta = 10), method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

Where **nll** is a function counting negative logliklihood. In the documentation for **mle** function "**start**" argument is defined like **"Initial values for optimizer."**

At first I've tried several values and that's how I got 0.1 and 10. But now I want to fit parts of my vector by some factor and this values aren't already suitable for all of them. At some of them I get an error:

```
 Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
 L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn' 
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lbeta(shape1[okk] + x[okk], shape2[okk] + size[okk] - x[okk]) :
NaNs produced
2: In lbeta(shape1[okk], shape2[okk]) : NaNs produced
```

Searching the internet I found a reasonable idea to start with values, that are counted by the [Method of Moments.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Method_of_moments) So I changed my 0.1 and 10 by its formulas, but I still get the same error.

Do you know some programmatical way to compute 100% suitable initial values for fitting beta with **mle**?

Sorry for my poor English and thanks a lot in advance for your insights!

Comment: do you have values in your data that are exactly 0.0 or exactly 1.0 ?  That will cause problems no matter what starting parameters you use ...

Comment: I suggest to consider the `fitdistrplus` R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/paper2JSS.pdf

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, there are lots of them! But it works with my full vector. (I build **nll** function using `dbetabinom.ab` from `VGAM` package.)

Comment: @MarcoSandri I've tried. There is `mmedist` function to compute alpha and beta with method of moments, but in mle method I still need start values. And it uses the same function `optim`, so I see no difference. May be you meant some exact function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no specific functions in mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to compute a 100% guaranteed suitable initial values, but here's how I could avoid this mistakes:

1. Just change a method to `"BFGS"`. It will show warnings, but no errors.

or

2. Specify the `lower` and `upper` arguments in mle.